# E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

```
E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:239)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:268)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1371)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:136)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1065)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I always get such type of warnings. Suggest a way to fix it.